# I'm I allowed to set the time driven trigger to run every 5 min?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a time driven trigger that would run the main function of my Google-apps-script. every 5 minutes (Gmail)
It's working fine, but I received the "Summary of failures" with the error message  " ***Service using too much computer time for one day*** " **7** times.

So my question is, I'm I allowed to set the time driven trigger to run my script every 5 minutes ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation there is a maximum of 1 hour computing time for normal gmail account.
See [reference here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that. It makes sense

 The total runtime of my script is approximately 20 seconds every 5 minutes, which is like 96 minutes every 24 hours.

I will change my trigger to run every 10 minutes instead.

Comment: 12x24x20 = 5760 >> 96 minutes ! too much indeed... maybe you can try to reduce execution time a bit more of limit its execution to work hours if it's doable for your use case ?

Comment: If I run it every 10 minutes, it should be fine. I need it to run frequently cause it basically sifts through the gmail inbox and process emails that needs processing and then sends a confirmation email to the original sender. I guess a 10 minutes window is not that bad.
since now it's 6x24x20 = 2880 >> 48 ( which is below the limit )